# Scalar division in a group of order p+1, p prime

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p=4q-1$ be a prime, with $q$ also prime.

Let $G=\{N,0,1,\dots,p-1\}$ be a set of $p+1$ elements (a special element $N$, and the $p$ non-negative integers less than $p$)

Define the internal law $\boxplus$ on $G$ by
$$a\boxplus b=\begin{cases}
b&\text{if }a=N\\
a&\text{if }b=N\\
N&\text{otherwise and if }a+b\equiv 0\pmod p\\
((a+b)^{-1}(a\,b-1))\bmod p&\text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$

$\boxplus$ is a commutative group law with $N$ the neutral element; the opposite $\boxminus a$ of any $a\ne N$ is $(-a)\bmod p$. Associativity is the only non-trivial property, and is easily established.

$(G,\boxplus)$ is a commutative group of order $p+1$. We can define scalar multiplication $\star$ with multiplicand $i\in\mathbb Z$ by:
$$i\star a=\begin{cases}
N&\text{if }i=0\\
((i-1)\star a)\boxplus a&\text{if }i>0\\
\boxminus((-i)\star a)&\text{if }i<0\\
\end{cases}$$

How can we efficiently compute scalar *division* by some large $i$ in this group, that is solve for $x$ the equation $i\star x=a$ given $i$ and $a$?

In my context, $p$ is a prime of maybe 256 bits.

Comment: The usual method is to compite $i^{-1}$ using the Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: @Derek Holt: What I'm missing is in what algebraic structure we compute $i^{-i}$. Sorry about that if it is silly.

Comment: It;s the finite field of order $p$, which is usually thought of as the field of integers modulo $p$.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Nearly so; I now believe$$i\star x=a\text{ and }\gcd(i,p+1)=1\implies x=(i^{-1}\bmod(p+1))\star a$$

Comment: I don't understand that. In your definitions, you were working mod $p$, not mod $p+1$.

Comment: @Derek Holt: the operation $\boxplus$ is defined modulo $p$, but the extra neutral element $N$ makes the group $(G,\boxplus)$ of order $p+1$. What matters is the order of the group $G$. I initially made the same error. My equation does not fully solve the problem, because $\gcd(i,p+1)=1$ might not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that $p+1=4q$, where $q$ is prime.

So the problematic cases are: 
$i \in \{2,4,q,2q\}$ (mod $(p+1)$).
It is sufficient to resolve $i=2$ and $i=2q$, because $4*x=a$ can be solved by repeatedly applying the method for $2*x=a$ and $q*x=a$ can be solved by multiplying by 2 on both sides.

Consider $2*x=b$.
If $b=N$, the solutions are $x=N$ and $x=0$.
If $b=0$, the solutions are $x=1,-1$.
In general, we have to solve: $\dfrac{(x^2-1)}{2x}=b$ (mod $p$).
That is: $x^2-2bx-1=0$, which boils down to finding the square-roots of $(b^2+1)$ modulo $p$.
This can be done for example, by the Tonelli-Shanks method.

The other case is: $(2q)*x=b$. Then $2b=N$.
This means that $b=N$ or $b=0$, so there are only 2 specific equations to worry about.

If $b=0$, then we have: $q*x=1$ or $q*x=-1$.
If $b=N$, then we have: $q*x=N$ or $q*x=0$.
That's all I've got so far in this case.